# React Render Children as component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I render children as components

I have a function that I want to pass as props to a dynamically rendered component

```
const someFuntion =() => true

const items =  [
 { name: <SomeComponent> props.someFuntion(Emerie) </SomeComponent>,
  age: <SomeOtherComponent> 22 </SomeOtherComponent>
 }
]



return ({ items.map(({name, age}) => {

   <div> {name someFuntion=someFuntion }    </div>
   <div> <name someFuntion=someFuntion/>    </div>
})})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const someFuntion = (children) => children
```

and on the render

```
<SomeComponent>{props.someFuntion(<Emerie />)}</SomeComponent>
```